# Pass data between tabs

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

I have a MainActivity (FragmentActivity) that has a FragmentTabHost.

```
public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("classA").setIndicator("Class A"),
            ClassA.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("classB").setIndicator("Class B"),
            ClassB.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("classC").setIndicator("Class C"),
            ClassC.class, null);
    }
}
```

ClassA, ClassB and ClassC are all Fragments `(android.support.v4.app.Fragment).`

I need to pass data (and call methods) on the Fragments. How can I get a reference of each of the Fragments, like this:

```
ClassA mClassAFragment = ???;
```

I’ve tried using `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()` and I’ve also tried exploring the capabilities of mTabHost. Nothing can get them.

Can you suggest a way to do this or suggest an alternative approach?

And i tried used this...

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putString("some id string", "your data");
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.setArguments(arguments);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentid, fragment).commit();
```

but i dont know how can use this `R.id.fragmentid` if my add tabs is well:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("classA").setIndicator("Class A"),
                ClassA.class, null);
```

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the Fragments in your Activity as public. Then in each Fragment you also reference the Activity.

In your Activity:

```
public ClassAFragment aFragment;
...
// during initialization:
aFragment = new ClassAFragment();
// or you get it from your TabHost
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
aFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("ClassA");
aFragment.mActivity = this;
// same with B and C
```

In your Fragments:

```
public MainActivity mActivity;
...
// in Fragment C
String newText = mActivity.aFragment.editText.getText().toString() + mActivity.bFragment.editText.getText().toString();
textView.setText(newText);
```

Comment: you can show me a example?   suppose we have 3 Fragments ..
Tab 1 ==> FragmentTab1
Tab 2 ==> FragmentTab2
Tab 3 ==> FragmentTab3

In Tab1 you have a EditText “Number 1″
In the Tab2 you have a EditText “Number 2″
In Tab3 should show the sum of the two numbers

As you do that?

Comment: I have updated my example filling textView in Fragment C with the concatenated string of editText's of both other Fragments.

Comment: I’ve tried using
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
aFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("ClassA");
aFragment.mActivity = this;
    But dont work ....aFragment is null... how can initialize him?

Comment: I solved the problem add a reference of activity inside the fragments..
Not  so:

    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

Something like:

    getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTab("MyTab");